# How to tell what kind of class/scene is runningScene?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to implement some logic in my application delegate methods. It would be really helpful to know which kind of scene is currently running.

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]` returns the scene currently running.

Is there some sort of comparison or function to check if it is an instance of my `[MainMenuLayer scene]` or [`gameScene scene]` or something like that?

I'm not quite sure to how to use `isKindOfClass` or `isEqual`, or if they are applicable in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been stumped on this for longer than anyone should.

This returns a CCScene:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]
```

You want the Instance of that scene which is of type MySceneClass (MenuScene for me), but the easiest way to get that is to tag it:

```
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
MenuScene *layer = [MenuScene node];
layer.tag = kTagGameLayer;

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild: layer];

// return the scene
return scene;
```

Then adjust your statement to use getChildByTag:

```
if([[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] getChildByTag:kTagGameLayer] isKindOfClass:[MenuScene class]]) {
        NSLog(@"current is MenuScene");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you assumed, you have to use isKindOfClass.

```
if ([[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] isKindOfClass:[MySceneClass class]]) {
    // Running is scene is of type MySceneClass
}
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to work. I tried using an NSLog to print when my [MainMenuScene class] is loaded, but it doesn't show. I also tried [MainMenuScene node]. Any ideas? Thanks